# shape rectangle corner(android)

Tags: android, xml

Sorry for my english. I want create linerLayout only top left corner radius. Example:

[image]

Its my xml:

```
 <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/getbonusClick"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/shape_corner_left_top"
                    android:orientation="vertical" />
```

Its my shape_corner_left_top

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  android:shape="rectangle">

    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#EC6118"/>
            <corners android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
                 android:bottomLeftRadius="0dip"
                 android:topLeftRadius="10dip"
                 android:topRightRadius="0.1dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

</selector>
```

Its result:

[image]

I need only radius left top corner. How i make made this?

Comment: why is topRightRadius="0.1dp"?

Comment: @Blackbelt if i set `topRightRadius="0dp"` nothing change

Comment: are you sure you are modifying the correct file? Do you have more than one version of the same file?

Comment: @Blackbelt now i give file name `asdasdasdswqweqwdasdasdasd.xml` and set  `android:background="@drawable/asdasdasdswqweqwdasdasdasd.xml"` but nothing change(

Comment: where are you testing it?

Comment: `android:background="@drawable/asdasdasdswqweqwdasdasdasd.xml"` is not a valid resource id. remove the `.xml`. With such a name, however, is prone to errors.

Comment: @Blackbelt thank, im testing in phone its work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just checked it, use this code, your problem will be solved

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <corners android:radius="10dp"
  android:bottomRightRadius="0dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp" 
  android:topLeftRadius="10dp" android:topRightRadius="0dp"/>
    <solid android:color="@android:color/black"/>
    <stroke android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"/>
</shape>
```

Preview on eclipse is not correct, run it on a device. You will find the solution.

Thanks